# find indices of values that sum up to a given value in R

Tags: r, sum

I've got a vector with observation intervals (in days) and would like to get the indices of the values that sum up to 30 days.

```
interval <- c(10, 12, 5, 5, 5, 5, 10)
```

so what I'd need is a vector like this. flag_endrow: 4, 6, 7
because:

```
sum(interval[1:4]) = 32  
sum(interval[2:6[) = 32  
sum(interval[3:7[) = 30
```

I tried doing this with a loop (see below), but failed. Any suggestions?

```
flag_endrow <- NULL
for (i in 1:length(interval)){
    for (j in i+1:length(interval)-1){
        if (sum(interval[i:j]) >= 30)
            {flag_endrow[i] <- j}
        break}
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I do not understand your example: the values with indices 4, 6, 7 give 20.

Comment: They have to sum up to at least 30, right?

Comment: Yes, see my edit just now

Answer (score 1):

End indexes are in vector `end` :

```
interval <- c(10, 12, 5, 5, 5, 5, 10)
begin <- NULL
end <- NULL
for (i in 1:(length(interval)-1)){
    for (j in (i+1):length(interval)){
        if (sum(interval[i:j]) >= 30){
            begin<- c(begin, i)
            end <- c(end, j)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work with only one loop if you use the cumsum() function.

```
interval <- c(10, 12, 5, 5, 5, 5, 10)

res <- c()

for(i in 1:length(interval)){
  v <- (cumsum(interval[i:length(interval)]) >= 30)
  val <- (which(v == TRUE)[1] + i - 1)
  if(!is.na(val)){
    res <- c(res, val )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an Integer Knapsack problem, which has a recursive solution. I am not so sure that multiple for loops can solve it.

Comment: I don't think so. My data are ordered and I don't want to change that order. So what I'm basically looking for is all the possible sequences that sum up to at least 30.

Comment: Following this answer, package `adagio` proposes a function called `subsetsum` : `subsetsum(interval, 30)` gives a possible solution.

Comment: I agree with @VincentGuillemot. But for 5-10 elements, I guess for-loops work. But for 100, you need a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a brute-force solution. It returns a list of all valid index vectors.

```
target <- 30

unlist(lapply(si <- seq_along(interval), function(x) {
  idx <- combn(si, x)
  idx_t <- which(colSums(matrix(apply(idx, 2, function(i) interval[i]),
                                ncol = ncol(idx))) >= target)
  lapply(idx_t, function(i2) idx[ , i2])
}), recursive = FALSE)
```